# Override asp.net form tag

Tags: asp.net

I have master page that contains the following asp.net form tag

```
<form id="CommerceMasterForm" runat="server">
```

on one page of my website i need to create normal html form from a user control

```
<FORM action="http://externaldomain.com" method="post">
```

How can i override the asp.net form tag and make it post like a typical html form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to include a close form tag before your new form tag.  Multiple Form Tags are allowed in HTML, but they can't be nested.  I use this trick with PayPal in some MasterPages and it works okay.

```
</FORM>
<FORM action="http://externaldomain.com" method="post">
```

This will prevent postback of any server controls from that point on though.

Comment: You forgot the <!--Hack--> indicator

Comment: wow, it worked. I don't know if that genius or criminal.

let's agree to never talk about this :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Cross Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)** to have the existing form submit to another page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Submit" PostBackUrl="TargetPage.aspx" />
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx):

> Under some circumstances, you might want to post one page to another page. ... In that case, you can configure certain controls on the page to post to a different target page. This is referred to as cross-page posting.
>
> Because cross-page posting is configured for individual controls, you can create a page that posts to different pages depending on which button the user clicks.

Comment: hi rex, thanks for the response. I should have clarified that i'm not using controls. ie i'm using old school html inputs as i need control over the name. ie <input name="totalPrice" value="x" /> it's submitting to a third party and they are expecting "totalPrice" etc. So basically i need a way for the master <form runat=server > not to render.